# Django-CMS CMSPlugin doesn't trigger pre_save/post_save signals

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to add the content of Django-CMS placeholders to the search index (using Algolia, but I guess this could apply for any indexing service, like Elasticsearch or similar) as soon as they are updated.

Using Django 1.10, django-cms 3.42, I have this model (simplified for this question):

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
from cms.models import CMSPlugin

class NewsItem(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=200),
    content = PlaceholderField('news_content')
```

I need to do some extra processing as soon as the model field 'content' is saved, and apparently the best way to check for that is to monitor the `CMSPlugin` model. So I look for saves using from `django.db.models.signals.post_save` like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CMSPlugin)
def test(sender, **kwargs):
    logger.info("Plugin saved.")
```

Now, the problem is that `post_save` is not triggered as I thought it would. With normal CMS Pages, I noticed that `post_save` is only triggered when a Page is published, but there is no apparent way to publish a placeholder when used outside the CMS.

The closest similar case I've found is [Updating indexes on placeholderfields in real time with django/haystack/solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927545/updating-indexes-on-placeholderfields-in-real-time-with-django-haystack-solr), but the suggested solution doesn't work.

How could I go about resolving this?

Thank you!

Comment: I highly recommend to not listen for pre or post save signals sent by cms objects like CMSPlugin. We've been removing all these from the core. What is the use case?

Comment: @Paulo I am trying to catch updates to placeholders so I can update the search index. I have (hopefully) clarified it in the question. Thank you!

Comment: I could have used it for resolving aldryn-forms#167, where copying a field makes the page inaccessible without dropping the plugin through python shell. I know that the problem can be resolved by adding validation that would prevent creation of a duplicate Field.name, but wasn't able to find a way of adding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also had the same search indexing problem when we were implementing [djangocms-algolia](https://gitlab.com/victor.yunenko/djangocms-algolia/) package, since a placeholder update doesn't trigger an update of the index.

For CMS pages we utilized `post_publish` and `post_unpublish` from `cms.signals` module [here](https://gitlab.com/victor.yunenko/djangocms-algolia/-/blob/b8327f0963a3742ced77f75ac671e991681c8c26/djangocms_algolia/signals.py).

And for cms apps that use placeholders (eg djangocms-blog) we attached the listeners to `post_placeholder_operation`, but beware that to make it work your ModelAdmin needs to inherit from `PlaceholderAdminMixin`:

```py
def update_news_index(sender, operation: str, language: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    placeholder: Optional[Placeholder] = None

    if operation in (ADD_PLUGIN, DELETE_PLUGIN, CHANGE_PLUGIN, CLEAR_PLACEHOLDER):
        placeholder = kwargs.get('placeholder')
    elif operation in (ADD_PLUGINS_FROM_PLACEHOLDER, PASTE_PLUGIN, PASTE_PLACEHOLDER):
        placeholder = kwargs.get('target_placeholder')
    elif operation in (MOVE_PLUGIN, CUT_PLUGIN):
        placeholder = kwargs.get('source_placeholder')
    else:
        pass

    if placeholder:
        post: Post = Post.objects.language(language_code=language).filter(content=placeholder).first()
        if post:
            post.save()


signals.post_placeholder_operation.connect(update_news_index, PostAdmin)
signals.post_placeholder_operation.connect(update_news_index, PageAdmin)
```